# What is the difference between loading a scene w/ .instance and using .new?

Tags: class, instance, godot

Working in Godot 3.2, I have a scene, `Player.tscn`. Near the top of `Player.tscn`, I have "`class_name Player`"

Now, when instantiating the `Player`, I have, as far as I see it, two options:

```
player = Player.new()
```

or

```
player = load("res://Player.tscn").instance() as Player
```

Now, the first version seems best to me...but it clearly isn't. If I use `.new()`, it claims that it has no children, and any method calls that attempt to get to its children (`.get_texture()` on a `Sprite`, e.g.), produces things like "`Attempt to call function 'get_texture' in base 'null instance' on a null instance`", because apparently `Player` has a no children.

Of course, doing it the second way, everything works fine. But why? Why can't I just use `.new()` if I've registered it as a class using `class_name`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Godot myself so I may be wrong, but I think it's because the .new() keyword is a language feature for loading single classes/nodes,

whereas .instance() is more of an engine feature that takes a packaged scene which is a combination of many classes/nodes, and restores their relative position in the tree, attaches scripts and resources, etc

### So if your player is a tscn scene, you'd do something like:

```
var player = load("res://etc/Player.tscn").instance()
get_tree().root.add_child(player)
player.global_transform = etc ...
```

---

which would load the root node of Player.tscn and all of its children (rigidbodies, collidershapes etc) into the scene tree, set their relative positions, connect the scripts and what have you

### Or if your Player is a class or a GDScript, you could do

```
var player = Player.new()
get_tree().root.add_child(player)
player.global_transform = etc ...
```

---

Which would add the single-node root player object only into the scene tree, but not any children

Once it's in the scene tree and _ready()'s triggered though, you can instantiate and attach the child component nodes (.new() > parent.add_child() > set transform) from the script itself